# How can i store hex value in string and get the value and size of the string

Tags: c++

I am trying to store a hex value in a string and latter retrieve it after some time, but while retrieving No value is coming size of the string is also coming 0. Sample code:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::string s;
    s.assign("\x00\x53"); // std::string s ="\x00\x53"
    cout<<s.size();
}
```

output is coming 0

Comment: See what happens when you change it to `"\x01\x53"`. You might wish to look up "null terminated strings".

Comment: *I am trying to store a hex value in a string and latter retrieve it after some time* – What do you mean by "hex value"? Something human-readable like `0xDEADBEAF` or ASCII values specified in hex notation in your code?

Comment: @ Mateen Ulhaq, "\x01\x53" is working, but the data i have is like "\x00\x53"

Comment: @ Swordfish, its ASCII values specified in hex notation

Comment: If your data contains a `'\0'` you can't feed it to functions expecting a zero terminated string like the `operator<<()` for `char const*`. Print the bytes individually.

Answer (score 0):

From C++14 onwards, we have the option of using [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), using that feature you can do this:

```
std::string s1 = "\x00\x53"s;
```

This will do what you expect and will return the correct value for `size()`.

If you cannot use C++14 features, you need to use a string constructor that will allow you to specify the length of the string. You can do this:

```
std::string s1( "\x00\x53", 2);
```

You can see demo for both versions [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e116f99ffe7694d1).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\\` instead of `\`:

```
s.assign("\\x00\\x53");
```

Now you have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string s;
    s.assign("\\x00\\x53"); // std::string s ="\x00\x53"
    cout << s.size() << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
8
\x00\x53
```